# When is the first input to `list_rec` not a constant function?

Tags: coq

The `list_rec` function has the type:

```
list_rec
 : forall (A : Type) (P : list A -> Set),
   P nil ->
   (forall (a : A) (l : list A), P l -> P (a :: l)%list) ->
   forall l : list A, P l
```

In all of the examples I've come up with, `P` is just a constant function that ignores the input list and returns the same type no matter what. For example, `P` might be `fun _ : list A => nat` or `fun _ : list A => list B`. What are some use cases for making the output of `P` dependent on the input?  Why is the type of `P` `list A -> Set` instead of just `Set`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can, for example, use `list_rec` with a non-constant `P` function to implement a function that converts a list to a vector (a length-indexed list).

```
Require List Vector.
Import List.ListNotations Vector.VectorNotations.
Set Implicit Arguments.

Section VecExample.
Variable A : Set.
Definition P (xs : list A) : Set := Vector.t A (length xs).

Definition list_to_vector : forall xs : list A, Vector.t A (length xs) := 
  list_rec P [] (fun x _ vtail => x :: vtail).
End VecExample.
```

You can compare it with the standard definition of the [`Vector.of_list`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html#of_list) function, which does exactly the same (`t` means [`Vector.t`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html#t) in the following code), using explicit recursion instead of hiding it behind a recursion principle:

```
Fixpoint of_list {A} (l : list A) : t A (length l) :=
match l as l' return t A (length l') with
  |Datatypes.nil => []
  |(h :: tail)%list => (h :: (of_list tail))
end.
```

A simple test:

```
Eval compute in list_to_vector [1;2;3].
Eval compute in Vector.of_list [1;2;3].
```

Both function calls return the same result:

```
= [1; 2; 3]
     : Vector.t nat (length [1; 2; 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to prove `s ++ [] = s`.

[Hint: Define `P` as `fun s => s ++ [] = s`.]